# JavaScript Regex not matching mobile number with international code

Tags: javascript, regex

Am trying to validate a mobile number `254777123456` against a regex `/^((254|255)[0-9]+){9,15}$/`, the mobile number should be prefixed with the country codes specified but the total length of the mobile number should not be more than 15 characters, doing this via javascript am getting null, can anyone point out what am doing wrong.

PS. Am using way more country codes than the ones I specified, I just put those two as a test before I add the others because they will all be separated by the pipe.

Comment: The only thing I have to add is you could maybe split the number into country code and remainder first, then check the country code?

Comment: What's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `^((254|255)[0-9]+){9,15}$` means, that pick at least 4 digits (of which first 3 should be either `254` or `255`) and whole of them must occur at least 9 times to max 15 times, which will mean the minimum length of string that will match should be of 36 characters. Which obviously you don't want. Your regex needs little correction where you need to take `[0-9]` part out and have `{9,12}` quantifier separately. Correct regex to be used should be this,

```
^(?:(?:254|255)[0-9]{9,12})$
```

This regex will match `254` or `255` separately and will restrict remaining number to match from 9 to 12 (as you want max number to be matched of length 15 where 3 numbers we have already separated out)

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M9xNDf/1)**

```js
var nums = ['254777123456','255777123456','255777123456123','2557771234561231']

for (n of nums) {
 console.log(n + " --> " + /^(?:(?:254|255)[0-9]{9,12})$/g.test(n));
}
```